# C++ dynamic array and set&get func

Tags: c++, arrays

i have started programing in c++ in the university, and i have a few questions:
1. when opening a cpp file, what do i need to write in the "#include" ?
iostream, using namespace std, and the H file of my class?
2. i was asked to create car class. one of the data members is car model.
so i wrote in the H file-> char* model;
now, i want to create set and get functions, but i dont know how to do it with dynamic arrays. can you please write it for me with the syntax? i have many functions to do with arrays, so i will learn from this example.
i have tried:

```
void MyCar::setCarModel(char *newName)
{
    strcpy(model,newName);
}
char* MyCar::getCarModel()
{
    return model;
}
```

can u tell me how to fix it?
thanks !

Comment: Try to compile it and see for yourself.

Comment: It would be simpler with `std::string`... missing some `const` currently.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "include" only the headers you need.

If you need to use input and output, then `#include <iostream>`.
If you wanted to use `std::string` instead of `char*`, you must `#include <string>`.
If you structure your class into two files, you will need to include the class header in the `.cpp` file with `#include "MyClass.h"`.
If you plan on using that class in the main function file, for example `main.cpp`, you need to include it there too, again with `#include "MyClass.h"`.

`using namespace std;` is bad practice, but use it if your lecturer wants it. This enables you to omit `std::` from everything in the `std` namespace, for example `cout`.

Regarding the class, you should consider looking up a basic tutorial related to getter and setter methods and use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

1. a. in your H file if you wish to use Input and Output streams use iostream.h

   b. you must specify a name and include for your H file in your H file.
2. If I understand correctly define a class Car declare a private data member type      char* called model ( the model of the car ). In set allocate a new char* array with the size of array newName. the get
   method is fine.